# Can't Connect VPN 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Edited: undeleted because of comment:

I can't run vpn:
Here's a simple terminal session:
$ sudo openvpn etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/USA-Dallas
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/USA-Dallas Use --help for more information."

"--help" gives me: "--help Options error: I'm trying to parse "etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/USA-Dallas" as an --option parameter but I don't see a leading '--'"

Comment: You simply have typo: there is no folder `etc`, but `/etc` exists. Add one slash and test again.

Comment: Thank you, N0rbert, but my mistake was worse than that: I neglected to re-boot. When I finally did that my original config worked: NetworkManager applet allowed me to select the OpenVPN configuration I needed.